# Can't beat GTA: San Andreas first mission

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I just started playing GTA: San Andreas on my PS2 and I keep failing my first real mission "Sweet & Kendl".

I have to follow my homies on a bike. However, I keep falling off the bike, and when I'm finally back on my bike, all my homies are long gone and there is no indication (arrow or something like that) which direction they went.

Am I missing something? Shouldn't there be some indication of where to go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is going fast enough to keep them in sight, but not so fast that you crash.  Just keep trying and you will get it.  Other than that there is not much other help on the first mission that I can recall.

Comment: Yeah I finally made it by trial and error. It is a pretty hard game.

Comment: It gets easier after you level up your stats.

Answer (score 4):

This mission is pretty easy.

Leave the bicycle, steal a car and follow them. Keep yourself close to them, as they won't be indicated on the map anymore. You can keep pace with them easily.

In case you lose them, they stop and wait for you at a particular location under the intersection of roadways, displayed in the below image.

[image: They stop and wait for you under the intersection of the roadways.]

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to keep tapping the <kbd>X</kbd> button to keep your speed up. I also had some trouble with this mission the first time I played.  You just have to get used to the controls on the bike through practice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tap <kbd>X</kbd> and try to keep up. I died a lot with the first one as well because your bike skill is low. You need to try in enough to learn the whole ride. That way if you fall off you can catch up because you know the way. Use handbrake, <kbd>R1</kbd> I think, and don't turn too sharply.